# Multiple conditional statement

Tags: php, conditional-operator

What's the best way to write this in PHP, so I know which condition fails and is easy to maintain? Without resorting to multiple if else statements...

```
if ((!$titleBlockPresent || !$leadBlock || ($allDoubleBlockCount !=2 || $allDoubleBlockCount!=1) ||$countFirstSmallShowBlocks !=2 ||$countSecondSmallShowBlocks !=2 ) && !$contentNotAvailableMessage)
{
    $this->fail("Block missing in the horizontal list of blocks on the non live carousel");
}
```

Comment: Simplify your logic so you are not checking 7 conditions at once.

Comment: You ask for the best way, but in your question you say "without resorting to multiple if else statements." I think the bottom line is that most (or many) people thinks multiple statements is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$shouldFail = FALSE;
switch(TRUE){
 case !titleBlockPresent:
    echo "No title block present<br/>";
    $shouldFail = TRUE;
 case !$leadBlock:
    echo "No lead block<br/>";

  // the rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move that check into the function, it'll be clear for you and anyone else looking at your code, and very easy to maintain, for example:

```
function tester($var1, $var2, $var3)
{
    if (!$var1) 
    {
        $this->fail("error1");
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!$var2) 
    {
        $this->fail("error2");
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!$var3) 
    {
        $this->fail("error3");
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

You could also add a comment to each `if` that needs further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I just come up with this, but noticed that it is very similar to GeoPhoenix's answer, just the other way around, may be worth checking this out, as well:

```
$bFail = false;

if(!$bFail && $contentNotAvailableMessage) $bFail = true;
if(!$bFail && !$titleBlockPresent ) $bFail = true;
if(!$bFail && !$leadBlock ) $bFail = true;

if(!$bFail && $allDoubleBlockCount != 2) $bFail = true;
if(!$bFail && $allDoubleBlockCount != 1) $bFail = true;
if(!$bFail && $countFirstSmallShowBlocks != 2) $bFail = true;
if(!$bFail && $countSecondSmallShowBlocks != 2) $bFail = true;

if($bFail) $this->fail("Block missing in the horizontal list of blocks on the non live carousel");
```